# When does macro substitution happen in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, macros, c-preprocessor

I was reading the book "*Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools (2nd Edition)*" by Alfred V. Aho. There is an example in this book (example 1.7) which asks to analyze the scope of `x` in the following  macro definition in **C**:

`#define a (x+1)`

From this example,

> We cannot resolve x statically, that is, in terms of the program text.
>
> In fact, in order to interpret x, we must use the usual dynamic-scope
>   rule. We examine all the function calls that are currently active, and
>   we take the most recently called function that has a declaration of x.
>   It is to this declaration that the use of x refers.

I've become confused reading this - as far as I know, macro substitution happens in the preprocessing stage, before compilation starts. But if I get it right, the book says it happens when the program is getting executed. Can anyone please clarify this?

Comment: It happens during preprocessing.  Look at the preprocessed output, `gcc -E foo.c` and you'd figure.

Comment: `I was the book "Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools (2nd Edition)"`...Interesting

Comment: This question isn't about when macro substitution happens, it's about understanding an explanation in a compiler book. Without the context that the quoted paragraph is in, answers are not going to be useful to future visitors of stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro itself has no notion of scope, at least not in the same sense as the C language has. Wherever the symbol `a` appears in the source after the `#define` (and before a possible `#undef`) it is replaced by `(x + 1)`.

But the text talks about the scope of `x`, the symbol in the macro substitution. That is interpreted by the usual C rules. If there is no symbol `x` in the scope where `a` was substituted, this is a compilation error.

The macro is not self-contained. It uses a symbol external to the macro, some kind of global variable if you will, but one whose meaning will change according to the place in the source text where the macro is invoked. I think what the quoted text wants to say is that we cannot know what macro `a` does unless we know where it is evoked.

Answer (score 1):

> I've become confused reading this - as far as I know, macro substitution happens in preprocessing stage, before compilation starts.

Yes, this is how a compiler works.

> But if I get it right, the book says it happens when the program is getting executed. Can anyone please clarify this?

Speaking without referring to the book, there are other forms of program analysis besides translating source code to object code (a.k.a. compilation). A C compiler replaces macros before compiling, thus losing information about what was originally a macro, because that information is not significant to the rest of the translation process. The question of the scope of `x` within the macro never comes up, so the compiler may ignore the issue.

Debuggers often implement tighter integration with source code, though. One could conceive of a debugger that points at subexpressions while stepping through the program (I have seen this feature in an embedded toolchain), and furthermore points inside macros which generate expressions (this I have never seen, but it's conceivable). Or, some debuggers allow you to point at any identifier and see its value. Pointing at the macro definition would then require resolving the identifiers used in the macro, as Aho et al discuss there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) one question, instead of using dynamic scoping (as Aho discusses there), the debugger should use static scoping for scope resolution, right?

Comment: @RafiKamal The debugger can do whatever it likes. "Should" is a loaded word. The features I described require dynamic scoping. Scoping is a high-level math concept, and it is what it is regardless of the compiler implementation. A debugger could be assisted by a static compiler which generates debug info each time the macro is used, to emulate all the results dynamic scoping could produce.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to be sure without seeing more context from the book, but I think that passage is at least unclear, and probably incorrect. It's basically correct about how macro definitions work, but not about how the name `x` is resolved.

```
#define a (x+1)
```

C macros are expanded early in the compilation process, in translation phase 4 of 8, as specified in [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.1.1.2. Variable names aren't resolved until phase 7).

So the name `x` will be meaningfully visible to the compiler, not at the point where the macro is defined, but at the point in the source code where the macro `a` is used. Two different uses of the `a` macro could refer to two different declarations of variables named `x`.

> We cannot resolve x statically, that is, in terms of the program text.

We cannot resolve it at the point of the macro definition.

> In fact, in order to interpret x, we must use the usual dynamic-scope
>   rule. We examine all the function calls that are currently active, and
>   we take the most recently called function that has a declaration of x.
>   It is to this declaration that the use of x refers.

This is not correct for C.  When the compiler sees a reference to `x`, it must determine what declaration it refers to (or issue a diagnostic if there is no such declaration). That determination does *not* depend on currently active function calls, something that can only be determined at run time. C is *statically scoped*, meaning that the appropriate declaration of `x` can be determined entirely by examining the program text.

At compile time, the compiler will examine symbol table entries for the current block, then for the enclosing block, then for the current function (`x` might be the name of a parameter), then for file scope.

There are languages that uses dynamic scoping, where the declaration a name refers to depends on the current run-time call stack. C is not one of them.

Here's an example of dynamic scoping in Perl (note that this is considered poor style):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

no strict "vars";

sub inner {
    print "    name=\"$name\"\n";
}

sub outer1 {
    local($name) = "outer1";
    print "outer1 calling inner\n";
    inner();
}

sub outer2 {
    local($name) = "outer2";
    print "outer2 calling inner\n";
    inner();
}

outer1();
outer2();
```

The output is:

```
outer1 calling inner
    name="outer1"
outer2 calling inner
    name="outer2"
```

A similar program in C would be invalid, since the declaration of `name` would not be *statically* visible in the function `inner`.